# Binding Derived DataTable to SQL-made DataTable to Fill Datagrid

Tags: datagrid, time, hyperlink, datatable, range

I am at a loss and have searched everywhere to figure out how to do this in a way I understand but still no luck. I am trying to show the time the client has free and what is scheduled on a day-to-day basis. Their schedule is kept on a server and displays their busy time. I pulled that data using a sql query and dropped that into a datatable called dtSched. I then created another datatable called dtTime to list the time from 6:00 AM - 10:00 PM by 15 minute increments. What I am now trying to do is combine both datatables to display all the time listed in dtTime and display where the client has time scheduled so I can show empty rows to allow appointments to be added and display scheduled time so appointments are not added in that time slot.

Here is my code to create the dtTime table (all time):

```
    Dim strStartDate As DateTime
    Dim strEndDate As DateTime

    strStartDate = DateValue(Now()) & " 6:00 AM"
    strEndDate = DateValue(Now()) & " 10:00 PM"

    While strStartDate <= strEndDate
        strStartDate = strStartDate.AddMinutes(15)
        Dim dr As System.Data.DataRow = dt.NewRow()
        dr("Time") = strStartDate
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)
    End While
```

Here is my sql-derived datatable dtSched (scheduled time):

```
Dim conn = New SqlConnection("Connection")
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE SCHED DATE = 'Date'"
Me.dataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, conn)
Dim commandBuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(Me.dataAdapter)
Dim dtSched As New DataTable()
dtSched.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
Me.dataAdapter.Fill(dtSched)
```

I was trying to use a GetData execution to tie the two datatables but it did not work:

```
Me.dataGrid.DataSource = Me.BindingSource1
    GetData("SELECT dt.Time, dtSched.Date, dtSched.ID, dtSched.Client, dtSched.StartTime, dtSched.Reason FROM dt LEFT JOIN dtSched ON dt.Time = dtSched.StartTime")
```

I am trying to connect both datatables by dt.Time and dtSched.StartTime. Then fill the datagrid. Any assistance anyone can provide would be downright awesome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured it out! Yea!

In case anyone has the same problem, I took my two datatables and did a merge using the following code:

```
        Dim pk1(0) As DataColumn
        Dim pk2(0) As DataColumn

        pk1(0) = dtTime.Columns("Time")
        dtTime.PrimaryKey = pk1

        pk2(0) = dtSched.Columns("Time")
        dtSched.PrimaryKey = pk2
        dtTime.Merge(tblSched, False, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore)

        Me.BindingSource1.DataSource = dtTime
```

I added the column names to my dtTime table that were in the dtSched table before merging and then boud dtTime to my datagrid and it was a wrap! I also added a third data table to the mix and it worked like a glove. What a relief!